# How to change the background of facebook like button

Tags: html, css

How can I change the background of the Facebook like button from white to something else?

Comment: I'm not sure the shady FB terms and conditions allow you to alter anything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in an iframe, so you cannot change the background.

> While you may scale the size to suit your needs,you may not modify the
>   Like button in any other way  (such as by changing the design).

Check this out:- http://www.facebook.com/brandpermissions/logos.php